# Interaction visuals in logistic regression

Tags: logistic, data-visualization, interaction

I am running a logistic model and am looking specifically at a 3 way interaction. Here is some descriptives on my data:
Outcome: mortality (y/n)
Var 1: gender (M/F)
Var 2: dichotomous lab value (above/ below certain critical cutoff- y/n)
Var 3: second dichotomous lab value (above/ below certain critical cutoff- y/n)

I am looking to see who is more at risk for the mortality outcome and have included an interaction for these terms in the model. My interaction p-value is not significant, but I want to report directions. Since I have 3 dichotomous variables, what would be the best way to present this (preferably graphically) in regards to who is more likely to experience mortality?

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 binary variables, so there are 8 different probabilities. Given this small number, you could just put them in a table and apply a heatmap on it. Downside: the reader would have to jump rows to see the effect of a single variable change.

[image]